# Upgrading phpunit to the latest version

Tags: php, phpunit

How can I upgrade PHPUnit to the latest version in windows 10? I tried to use pear command but it fails. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEAR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method) was discontinued years ago. A simple search should have yielded the [official website](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html).